# display data on wordpress site using mindbody api

Tags: wordpress, mindbody

I have an account on clients.mindbody.com and I have created class schedules and staff lists etc and I want to show class schedules on my WordPress site by calling an API or iframe.how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Start with creating a developer account and reading documentation at https://developers.mindbodyonline.com

Comment: actually, i want to link my mind-body account in healcode to display data on my site,how can i create or use login credentials in mind-body branded web tools because i cant create account in brander web tools here is the link http://manager.healcode.com/users/sign_in